# Memory management with a UIButton

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, uibutton

I've been having some issues with getting a good grasp on memory management. I'm adding images and buttons to the main view using a loop. The images release properly, but not the buttons.

My question boils down to, given the following code, why when i press the button to clear the screen, is the memory not release? The UIButton is autoreleased from UIButtonType custom, and setImage autoreleases transportation map.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *homeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [homeButton setFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    [homeButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [homeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TransportationMap.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    homeButton.tag = 9399;
    [homeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clearScreen) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:homeButton];
}

-(void)clearScreen 
{    
    for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "The images release properly, but not the buttons"?

Comment: That was in reference to my actual program, where i'm adding both images and text, as well as buttons. I have no issues with the images releasing properly, only buttons. This is just and example of code where I implement a button with a custom image, and the memory leaks after the button is removed from the screen

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are not allocating any memory in any of this code, so you should not need to release anything either.

Comment: While the button is on the screen, memory is allocated for "TransportationMap", the button's image. When i clear the button using the clearScreen method, that memory remains in use. According to instruments.

Comment: Instruments is not infallable unfortunately, particularly with autoreleased items.  However assuming it is somehow correct, consider looking at creating a new NSAutoreleasePool before the button is created then you can call -drain at the end to force the dealloc of the button.

Answer (score 1):

You're placing concerned where you need not place them... Apple's rules of memory management state that anything you own (anything you alloced or copied or retained), you are responsible for releasing. Beyond that, you generally shouldn't care about what's going on. Apple could be caching images for its own purposes, etc... it is the OS's responsibility to deal with that, not yours. In your code, you are obeying all the rules (as far as I can tell)... you aren't allocing or retaining the button or the image. Therefore, you shouldn't be worried about releasing or freeing up that memory. Let the framework deal with it.

Comment: Interesting, well in that case I just spent an amount of time i'm a little embarrassed to admit chasing down a memory leak in my program that does not exist. I expected the program's memory usage via instruments to exactly reflect the releases in my program. Thanks for the help!